# how to use variebles in list[variable]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

```
import sys
sort = []   #list
def myMax(mylist):   # function instead of max()
    listadd = 0
    plus1 = listadd + 1
    for listadd in range(a):
    if sort[listadd] > sort[plus1, a]: # where i get error
        return sort[listadd]
while True:
try:
    a = int(input(" How many numbers do you want to compare: "))
    break
except ValueError:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR\n')
    sys.stderr.write(' Try Again... \n')
for i in range (a):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
            sort.append(n)
            break
        except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write('ERROR\n')
            sys.stderr.write(' Try Again... \n')
print(myMax(sort), " is the biggest number! ") # function instead of max()
SystemExit()
```

Simple max program error.

Program to find max. of some numbers without using `max()` and install required modules.

How do you make a function that does the same thing?

Comment: Your code is not valid python.

Comment: for which one it is python 3 . 2

Comment: it gives an error thats what i am asking how to fix it

Comment: Given the quality of this question, the best answer we can give is "fix the error".

Comment: @timgeb This question deserves to have the python tag removed, as it isn't python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over each item in the list, checking if it is larger that the highest one so far.

```
x=lst[0]
for i in lst:
    if i > x:
        x = i
return x
```

Comment: Or don't. Why would you put effort into an answer if OP clearly put no effort into the question?

Comment: i am a beginner in python

Comment: @timgeb Fair enough, but I like to consider myself kindhearted

Comment: I renamed your list variable (the name `list` is already taken by the builtin list).

Comment: @timgeb Thanks, I didn't think of that!